# history.pushState why twice back issue?

Tags: pushstate, html5-history, popstate

I have like this code when i running click function need to back 2 units for before page why twice ?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.pager .pages ol li a,#narrow-by-list dd ol li a,.currently ol li a,.actions a').on('click' ,function(event){
        window.history.pushState({page: this.href}, null, this.href);
        $('html, body').animate({
             scrollTop: $("#uppp").offset().top - 60
        }, 1300,'easeInOutExpo');
        // event.preventDefault();              
    });
    $(document).on("scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.which > 0 || e.type === "mousedown" || e.type === "mousewheel") {
            $('html, body').stop();
        }
    });
    window.onpopstate = function(event) {
        var state = event.originalEvent.state;
        window.location.href = document.location;
    };
});
```